# specifying in terraform that the OS is linux for azurerm_function_app

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cli

I have the following `azurerm_function_app` terrform section:

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "main" {
  name                      = "${var.storage_function_name}"
  location                  = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  app_service_plan_id       = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.main.id}"
  storage_connection_string = "${azurerm_storage_account.main.primary_connection_string}"
  https_only                = true

  app_settings {
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" = "${azurerm_application_insights.main.instrumentation_key}"
  }
}
```

How can I specify the OS is linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there is not much documentation, I used following technique to construct terraform template.

1. Create the type of function app you want in azure portal

   [image]
2. Import same resource using terraform import command.

> terraform import azurerm_function_app.functionapp1
>   /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/mygroup1/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/functionapp1

3. following information will be retrieved

   > ```
   >   id = /subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/xxxx
   >   app_service_plan_id = /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/xxxx
   >   app_settings.% = 3
   >   app_settings.FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = node
   >   app_settings.MACHINEKEY_DecryptionKey = xxxxx
   >   app_settings.WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION = 10.14.1
   >   client_affinity_enabled = false
   >   connection_string.# = 0
   >   default_hostname = xxxx.azurewebsites.net
   >   enable_builtin_logging = false
   >   enabled = true
   >   https_only = false
   >   identity.# = 0
   >   kind = functionapp,linux,container
   >   location = centralus
   >   name = xxxxx
   >   outbound_ip_addresses = xxxxxx
   >   resource_group_name = xxxx
   >   site_config.# = 1
   >   site_config.0.always_on = true
   >   site_config.0.linux_fx_version = DOCKER|microsoft/azure-functions-node8:2.0
   >   site_config.0.use_32_bit_worker_process = true
   >   site_config.0.websockets_enabled = false
   >   site_credential.# = 1
   >   site_credential.0.password =xxxxxx
   >   site_credential.0.username = xxxxxx
   >   storage_connection_string = xxxx
   >   tags.% = 0
   >   version = ~2
   > ```

   4. From this I build following terraform template

> ```
>     provider "azurerm" {
>
>     }
>
> resource "azurerm_resource_group" "linuxnodefunction" {
>     name     = "azure-func-linux-node-rg"
>     location = "westus2"
> }
>
> resource "azurerm_storage_account" "linuxnodesa" {
>     name                     = "azurefunclinuxnodesa"
>     resource_group_name      = "${azurerm_resource_group.linuxnodefunction.name}"
>     location                 = "${azurerm_resource_group.linuxnodefunction.location}"
>     account_tier             = "Standard"
>     account_replication_type = "LRS" 
> }
>
> resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "linuxnodesp" {
>     name                = "azure-func-linux-node-sp"
>     location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.linuxnodefunction.location}"
>     resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.linuxnodefunction.name}"
>     kind                = "Linux"
>     reserved            = true
>
>     sku {
>         capacity = 1
>         size     = "P1v2"
>         tier     = "PremiunV2"
>     }
> }
>
> resource "azurerm_function_app" "linuxnodefuncapp" {
>     name                      = "azure-func-linux-node-function-app"
>     location                  = "${azurerm_resource_group.linuxnodefunction.location}"
>     resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.linuxnodefunction.name}"
>     app_service_plan_id       = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.linuxnodesp.id}"
>     storage_connection_string = "${azurerm_storage_account.linuxnodesa.primary_connection_string}"
>
>     app_settings {
>         FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME     = "node"
>         WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION = "10.14.1"
>     }
>
>     site_config {
>         always_on = true
>         linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|microsoft/azure-functions-node8:2.0"
>         use_32_bit_worker_process = true
>         websockets_enabled = false            
>     }
> }
> ```

Let us know your experience with this. I will try to test few things with this.

Comment: I think the config provided here creates a premium plan. Is there a way to create consumption plan on Linux OS for a function app ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to specify that in app_service_plan block

```
Kind = "Linux"
```

kind - (Optional) The kind of the App Service Plan to create. Possible values are Windows (also available as App), Linux and FunctionApp (for a Consumption Plan). Defaults to Windows. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.

NOTE: When creating a Linux App Service Plan, the reserved field must be set to true.

Example from Terraform doc

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "azure-functions-cptest-rg"
  location = "westus2"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "test" {
  name                     = "functionsapptestsa"
  resource_group_name      = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  location                 = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "test" {
  name                = "azure-functions-test-service-plan"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  kind                = "Linux"

  sku {
    tier = "Dynamic"
    size = "Y1"
  }
  properties {
    reserved = true
  }
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "test" {
  name                      = "test-azure-functions"
  location                  = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  app_service_plan_id       = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.test.id}"
  storage_connection_string = "${azurerm_storage_account.test.primary_connection_string}"
}
```

Comment: This is great.  Is it possible to set the runtime e.g. node and the function app runtime so it is 2?

This does not appear to be documented anywhere or could you point me to a link?

Comment: you can't specify like azure portal but there is option to specify custom linux image..not sure if that works for you
    site_config = {
        linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|{path_to_registry}/{image_name}:{tag}"
    }

Comment: site_config has limited options in azurerm_function_app compared to azurerm_app_service

Comment: sort of curious as to why you would use this at all if you can’t specify whether it is a node python etc. app

Comment: I am not sure about that option under azurerm_function_app.i need to try ..but in app_service_plan you can specify various runtime options.

Comment: I'm hopefully missing something but it seems pretty useless without these options

Comment: you can actually just specify the node version like this `linux_fx_version = "node:10.3"`

Comment: hey..wait for 1 hour..I was working on your issue and decoded completely..I will post  as another answer..also technique used